# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "student". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, next.js13

So far, none of the existing solutions on StackOverflow have solved my issue, so I'm reposting my problem. I'm using NextJS 13 with app routing and mongoose. It seems that I get this message ONLY when deleting my .next directory and re-building. I then have to re-run my mongoose scripts and repopulate my MongoDB. Then all code works. My code:

```
-- student-session-model.js
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
const MODEL_NAME = "student-session";

const schema = new Schema(
  {
    startTime: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    endTime: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    statements: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    completedScenes: {
      type: Array,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    student: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "student",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.models[MODEL_NAME] ||
  mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME, schema);
```

...and below is the route that connects the DB and calls the model. (I've also tried putting the "studentSessionModel" import BEFORE the "dbConnect" import and get the same error):

```
-- student-results.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { dbConnect } from "@/app/core/db";
import studentSessionModel from "@/app/core/models/student-session-model";

export async function POST(req) {

  try {
    await dbConnect();
    const data = await studentSessionModel.find().populate("student");

    return NextResponse.json({ data });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Student Results route err: ", err);
    return NextResponse.json({ err });
  }
}
```

Comment: You've shown `student-session` but the error is about `student`. Did you create `student` model?

Comment: @konrad - thanks for your input, but I've posted an update below

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I've figured out what was happening. In my app, a student logs in and takes a quiz. An admin logs in and gets results. I realized that the "student-model" NEVER gets run/registered if I go straight to the admin area and check results.(This obviously is a development thing). So after deleting the .next directory and re-building, THEN going straight to the admin area, the student-model never got run again. I just tested this by going through the test again and then logging in to admin and the above code worked fine. Thanks for indulging, and I apologize. But maybe someone will benefit from my stupidity...;-)